# Isolating sizes written in various ways while maintaining it in group 1

Tags: regex

Wiktor helped me to isolate values when i had multiple sizes:

`(?i)([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)[/-]([a-z\d]+(?:[/-][a-z\d]+)?)`

However i was unable to look into how it could handle a single size all together

Test cases:

```
S1 - XXS/XS-S/M
S1 - 40-42-36-38
XXS/XS
40-42
40
```

With the above examples i am able to match all the relevant sizes, but not the last one "40"

How could i look into grabbing this value as well if its a single value. However it seems that won't be doable with the current.

So i have been wondering if it perhaps could be possible to grab the higlighted so that i always get the result of the first size in group 1

**S1 - XXS/XS**-S/M

**S1 - 40-42**-36-38

**XXS**/XS

**40**-42

**40**

Desired values are highlighted with bold.

Pretty much i just have to make sure that in the end i have two results which showcase each size - whatever is in front doesn't matter!

Really hope someone can help me on the right path here - the sizes are always separated by - or / or " - " and " / "

Comment: For the given examples, and if lookarounds are supported, perhaps `\b(?:[a-z]\d\s*-\s*(?:[a-z]+/[a-z]+|\d+-\d+)|(?<!-)(?:(?:[a-z]+)(?=/)|\d+))\b` https://regex101.com/r/uLmQDB/1 or using an anchor `^(?:[a-z]+\d*(?:\s*-\s*[a-z\d]+[/-][a-z\d]+)?|\d+)\b` https://regex101.com/r/WMT2op/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string should match from the start of the string, one option could be using an anchor to assert the start of the string.

```
(?i)^(?:[a-z]+\d*(?:\s*-\s*[a-z\d]+[/-][a-z\d]+)?|\d+)\b
```

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for case insensitive match
- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[a-z]+\d*` Match 1+ chars a-z and optional digits
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\s*-\s*` Match `-` between optional whitespace chars
    - `[a-z\d]+[/-][a-z\d]+` match either `-` or `/` between chars a-z or digits
  - `)?` Close group and make it optional
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `)\b` Close non capture group and a word boundary to prevent a partial match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GdgGmV/1)

Another idea if lookarounds are supported, is to use a word boundary on the left and isolate the specific parts that you want to match

```
(?i)\b(?:[a-z]\d\s*[-/]\s*(?:[a-z\d]+[/-][a-z\d]+)|(?<!-)(?:[a-z]+(?=/)|\d+))\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bI2IjU/1)

Or using a capture group capturing what you want, and match optional non whitespace chars to prevent a partial match for the given examples.

```
(?i)\b([a-z\d]+(?:\s*-\s*[a-z\d]+[/-][a-z\d]+)?)\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pwHCWw/1)